# random connection error cant connect to mysql database server 10060

Tags: mysql, networking

Our Application is using mysql database from remote linux server at port 3306
Application is connecting to database server using TCP/IP protocol from windows xp service pack 3 machine.Application works well almost all time but some times it is giving following error randomly "[MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver]Can't connect to MySQL Server on 'IP Adderss' (10060)". Only one desktop user is facing this issue from around 240 users.

Application is developed in VB6.
Database server: mysql 5.1.51

can any one suggest possible cause of this error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error occurs randomly in just one client machine , we have change network card on particular machine and then user has not face same issue from last week.It was due to interrupted network connectivity of client machine to database server